# Генерация SSL сертификатов letsencrypt

Tags: https, certbot

Изучал и пытался сгенерировать сертификат для домена, но оказалось есть лимит, о котором я не знал. Генерировал через certbot. В итоге папку из сертификатом удалил, и сгенерировать нельзя, так как пишет ошибку "Error creating new cert :: too many certificates already issued for exact set of domains". Я только начал его изучить и как на зло теперь не смогу сгенерировать сертификат для домена.Можно ли как-то это сейчас сделать в обход ошибки или каким способом можно ещё сгенерировать сертификат?

Comment: Немного подождать?

Comment: [Тут](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/) читали?